# "You go to a party with 500 guests." -> has the party 500 or 501 guests in total?

Tags: phrase-meaning, numbers

I read the following in a problem statement in {1}:

> You go to a party with 500 guests.

Has the party 500 or 501 guests in total? Or is it ambiguous?

---

{1} Bertsekas, Dimitri P., and John N. Tsitsiklis. Introduction to probability. Vol. 1. Belmont, MA: Athena Scientific, 2002.
Harvard

Comment: It's ambiguous. But this is hair-splitting logic, not really related to learning or using English.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Some languages may not have such PP-attachment ambiguities.

Comment: And some languages may not support the other ambiguity regarding whether ***with*** attaches to the verb ***go*** or the noun ***party*** (where in the former case, there might *already* be thousands of guests at the party). That might be a meaningful thing to ask about, but frankly I don't think [the difference between pre-increment and post-increment](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-pre-increment-and-post-increment-operator-in-C++) is a meaningful aspect of "natural" languages - it's just a computer thing.

Comment: I agree that it's ambiguous.  Given that this is a probability textbook, I'm going to guess that the total number is supposed to be 500, because *n*/500 is a lot easier to grasp than *n*/501.

Comment: Does the party have 500 or 501 guests? Answer: It depends on whether  you count yourself as a guest.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Pardon my explanation point (as we call it over here) but it's not ambiguous in the least! Should a damsel say to me _"You go to a party with 500 guests..."_ I will assume that had she meant to say there were 50**1** guests there, she'd have said just that. I have no cause to doubt what she says.

Comment: @P. E. Dant: Personally, I'd assume the party already "exists" before "you" go to it, so if said damsel really did know and care about expressing the *exact* number of people at the party, she'd probably be referring to how many were *already* present. If only because in my mind the verb ***to go*** primarily refers to ***travelling** [towards the party]*, rather than ***attending** it*, so the addressee isn't "yet" there to be counted (he's effectively *en route*).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's ambiguous, but we can make a guess as to the meaning.  It depends on how you interpret *with*.

1. > I'm going to a party.  (What kind of party?)  A party with 500 guests.

In this interpretation, "with 500 guests" refers to how many people will be at the party.  This number presumably includes the speaker.

Because the source is a probability textbook, I would say that this is the likely interpretation.  Hypothetical scenarios in probability usually prefer round numbers.

2. > I'm going, with 500 guests, to a party.

In this interpretation, you are going along with 500 other people, for a total 501 guests.  This interpretation implies that *you are the one bringing these guests*.  There may even be more people at the party, if there are others who brought guests as well.

If the number were smaller than 500 (say, 3 or 4), and if the quote were from a real person rather than a textbook, this is the interpretation I would tend to go with.

Comment: The question title specifically focuses on the issue of whether the number of people ***at*** the party is 500 or 501 (i.e. - does the number *include the speaker?*). So it's not asking about the other potential ambiguity (is 500 the number of people who specifically ***went with*** me, or *the total number of people at the party?*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think the ambiguities are closely related.  Whether the speaker is included depends on whether the number refers to those at the party or those that the speaker brought.  I've edited my answer to note this.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of the statement hinges on the meaning of **with**, and there is also an assumption that you are not crashing the party but are  an invited guest.

"a party to which 500 people had been invited" (and you are one the invitees) [ergo 500]

"a party where 500 guests [of an unknown number of invitees] have already shown up" (and you are an invitee) [ergo 501]

Or if you are a party-crasher, 500.